# How do I change the colors displayed in cygwin rxvt?

Tags: bash, cygwin, rxvt

When I print `"\[\e[34m\]sometext"` I get some text in blue, but can I specify the shade of blue somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an ANSI escape sequence, which has very limited color options.  I use an .Xdefaults file (explained in [this tutorial](http://freemode.net/archives/000121.html)).  These options won't make your shell prompt all colorful, but is used by editors such as vim.

Be aware that .Xdefaults can be picky about UNIX (CR) vs Windows (CRLF) line endings.  Use d2u or u2d to switch line endings as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If your rxvt has 256 colors enabled, you can use extended color codes (e.g. "^[[38;5;36m"). Try this [script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349) to test if your terminal has 256 colors enabled. Probably you need to patch/recompile it or download another version. I recommend [this](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/) tutorial.